Create a view between two databases in same PostgreSQL sever
There is a table called TableA and anther table called TableB both of them are in same sever i want to create a viwe called TEST in TableA which takes Username, ID columns to the view from suser table in TableB
so how can I do this in PostgreSQL I used several tries and learn I need to create a foreign data wrapper and a db-link I want to know is there another way to do this easily because creating db-link make the process slow

Would you show us what you tried, please?

No,there is no other way to access data in another database except using a foreign data wrapper (recommended) or dblink.
If the performance is not good enough, tune the query or put all the tables into a single database.

thanks a find out I can do this by using foreign data wrapper thanks for your help
